# C Pointer confusion

Tags: c, struct, pointers, segmentation-fault

I want to store a string in memory and read it later:

```
$$->desc.constant->base.id =  (char*)malloc(200);
sprintf($$->desc.constant->base.id, "%f", $1);
printf("->%s\n", $$->desc.constant->base.id); //LINE A
printf("->%i\n", $$->desc.constant); //LINE B

//SOME OTHER CODE

//Then, later on in a function call:

printf("%i", expr->desc.constant); // LINE D
printf("%s", expr->desc.constant->base.id); // LINE C
```

Although Line B and Line D show the same address, the printf in Line C fails with a Segmentation fault. What am I missing?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: You should never cast the return value from malloc. Also, you should test if it is 0. If malloc returned 0, an error occured. Read http://www.stanford.edu/~blp/writings/clc/malloc-cast.html

Comment: is this really C? I've never seen the dollar character be used as a variable name in C.

Comment: It is probably part of the actions of a Yacc grammar.

Comment: $ is technically illegal to use in C identifiers; some compilers allow it if you enable a certain exception.  With gcc, you can do that with the -fdollars-in-identifiers option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
printf("->%i\n", $$->desc.constant); //LINE B
```

That is invalid. As you show the line prior to it that `constant` is actually a pointer, you cannot treat it as if it were of type `int`. They don't necassarily have the same sizeof and alignment. Use the format used for `void*`. It will output memory addresses properly:

```
printf("->%p\n", (void*)$$->desc.constant); //LINE B
```

Comment: This does not address why the code segfaults - which is the main question.

Comment: it could segfault because of that, since what he does causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

1. **always** check `malloc`'s return value.
2. `sprintf` -> `snprintf`
3. `"%f"` -> `"%.*g"`

Here's an example:

```
/** $ gcc print_number.c -o print_number */
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const char* number_format = "%.*g";
  const int ndigits = 15;
  assert(ndigits > 0);
  const int maxlen = ndigits + 8 /* -0.e+001, Infinity */ + 1 /* '\0' */;

  char *str = malloc(maxlen);
  if (str == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: malloc\n");
    exit(1);
  }    

  double number = 12345678901234567890.123456789012345678901234567890;
  /** `number = 0/0` crashes the program */;

  printf("number: %f\t", number);

  int len_wouldbe = snprintf(str, maxlen, number_format, ndigits, number);
  assert(len_wouldbe < maxlen);

  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
number: 12345678901234567000.000000 1.23456789012346e+19
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe between the time of the two pieces of code you have since `free`d the string?

```
$$->desc.constant->base.id =  (char*)malloc(200);
sprintf($$->desc.constant->base.id, "%f", $1);
printf("->%s\n", $$->desc.constant->base.id); //LINE A
printf("->%i\n", $$->desc.constant); //LINE B

//SOME OTHER CODE
// which happens to do
free($$->desc.constant->base.id);

printf("%i", expr->desc.constant); // LINE D
printf("%s", expr->desc.constant->base.id); // crash
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the program is producing a segmentation fault, I think the problem is most likely that the structure designated (pointed to) by `expr->desc.constant` has been reused since the space was allocated, or possibly the space was never really allocated at all.

The code exhibits various venial sins, such as using `sprintf()` instead of `snprintf()`, and gratuitously allocating 200 bytes for the string representation of a floating point number.  (You are very unlikely to need that much space; if you do, you should most probably allow for at least 100 more digits than you have, since the exponent range for floating point numbers is usually +/-308, and the only reason you'd need 200 characters is to allow for incredibly large or incredibly tiny numbers.)

You have shown that `$$->desc.constant` points to the same place, but you have not shown how that space is allocated.  You then allocate the string space in `$$->desc.constant->base.id`, without clearly allocating the space for `base`.