# sprintf access violation

Tags: null, char, segmentation-fault, printf

I have a problem with the following code:

```
for(i = 0;(i - 1)< n;i++)
{
char* b;
sprintf(b, "%d", i);
}
```

It compiles fine but when I run it it give me the infamous "0XC0000005 Access Violation" error. I have tried setting b to NULL, "", "0", 0 and a bunch of other stuff but then I get the "0XC0000005 Access Violation" error or "Expression: string != NULL. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346499/c-pointer-confusion#346598

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sprintf` writes data into an existing buffer, which you pass into it as the first parameter. Currently you're not specifying a value for b at all, which means (IIRC in C) the value could be anything. If you set it to NULL or 0, `sprintf` is going to try to write into memory starting at address 0.

You need to create a buffer of the appropriate size, so that sprintf can write into it. For example:

```
for(i = 0;(i - 1)< n;i++)
{
    char b[10];
    sprintf(b, "%d", i);
}
```

Whether that's *actually* how you want to allocate the buffer depends on what your real code wants to do with the results, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Umm... Your pointer to b contains garbage since you haven't initialized it or allocated space.
Springtf requires you to have allocated a destination buffer space...

At a minimum, you want something like char b[50] or whatever maximal size you expect, not just a char*.

Answer (score 1):

A char* is an uninitialized pointer to a char or char array. You need to define a buffer char[10], otherwise the target address of sprintf is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

sprintf requires to pass it an already allocated character buffer large enough to store any possible result.  This is highly subject to buffer overflows - you probably want to use the safer snprintf instead.  One inefficient but safe way to do that:

```
int bufsize = snprintf(NULL, 0, formatstring, ...);
char *buffer = malloc(bufsize+1); # count doesn't include trailing nul
if (buffer == NULL) out_of_memory_error();
snprintf(buffer, bufsize+1, formatstring, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! Since I needed a char* I rewrote the code to:

```
for(i = 0;(i - 1)< n;i++)
{
char* b;
char a[100];
b = a;
sprintf(b, "%d", i);
}
```

and it works like a charm.  I can finally now get on with my life! Once again thank you very very much!

Comment: You could have just used a in place of b there.  What are you doing with it afterward?  If your char* points to an auto array like that, it won't be reliable after the block in which the array is declared.